# Transformar un string en un formato .Date valido para comprar fechas

Tags: javascript, function

Hola espero que estén bien, tengo la siguiente inquietud, estoy recibiendo de una base de datos el siguiente JSON, y en ese JSON tengo dentro de un objeto la fecha que necesito `"Start_Date": "2022-10-04 11 AM",` con ese "formato"

```
"Incoming": {
                "End_Date": "2022-10-04 11 AM",,
                "Id": "000009",
                "Start_Date": "2022-10-04 11 AM",
                "TE": 6
            }
```

Pasa que necesito comparar la fecha actual con la fecha del campo `"Start_Date"` y además sumarle el campo `"TE":`(Que serian horas), a la fecha del campo `"Start_Date"`. Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma en una función

```
  function compararFechas (){

  var TE = Incoming.TE; 
  var fecha = Incoming.Start_Date;
  var ConFecha = fecha.substring(0, 10);
  var NewFecha = new Date(ConFecha);
  NewFecha.setHours(NewFecha.getHours()+TE);
  var FechaActual = new Date();

  if (NewFecha > FechaActual){
  return 'ok';
}
  else {
    return 'no';
  }
}
```

Pero no me está funcionando, creo que es por el formato en el que viene la hora de la base de datos =/ , Agradecería mucho la ayuda

Comment: para comprar fechas???

Comment: debajo de  `function compararFechas` pone `console.log(Incoming)` y lo ejecutas; verifica en la consola del navegador que sale, le tomas foto y lo pones en tu pregunta.

Comment: El formato que usas de fecha no parece el adecuado segun [esta nota](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#sect2) de la documentación de MDN. Además, le quitas la hora al hacer esto: `var ConFecha = fecha.substring(0, 10);`.

Comment: Cambia esa línea por esta: `var ConFecha = fecha.substring(0, 13) + ':00';`  para que al menos reconozca mejor las horas (no es ideal, ya te digo, lo ideal es el formato que aparece en la [nota](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#sect2) que he comentado antes), y luego haz lo que te dicen en la respuesta de @LPZadkiel para compararlos. ([ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/spr1e6dn/1/))

Comment: Ok voy a realizar los cambios, mil gracias y ya estoy comentando

Answer (score 0):

La comparación de fechas en javascript se hace con `getTime` para evitar errores:

```
if (NewFecha.getTime() > FechaActual.getTime()){
  return 'ok';
} else {
  return 'no';
}
```

Esto lo puedes comprobar con el siguiente código:

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date(d1);
d1 === d2 // false
d1 == d2 // false
d1.getTime() === d2.getTime() // true
```